Is it possible to do custom thread scheduling without a kernel driver on windows?
I see the windows UMS (user mode scheduling) api is completely discontinued, and I'm interested in learning about/writing my own scheduler. Is there a way to do true custom thread scheduling in user mode windows nowadays? Would I need a kernel driver? If so, are there any resources other folks have come across for learning this kind of thing?
Looked at windows UMS, is totally discontinued.

The closest thing is fibers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers
